# import image,lay filter on top and then plot data

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

I would like to plot data on top of an imported picture in R. I would also like to lay a filtering layer on the image if possible, like controlling transparency color in ggplot2 with the alpha value:

here is an example to work on:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(jpeg)
library(scales)
library(grid)

#picture from internet
myurl <- "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Apollonian_spheres.jpg"
z <- tempfile()
download.file(myurl,z,mode="wb")
pic <- readJPEG(z)
file.remove(z) # cleanup

x <- sample(1:10, replace=T, 10)
y <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i", "j")

df <- data.frame(y,x)

p <-ggplot(df, aes(y, x, fill=y)) + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(pic, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), 
                    -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="red",width=0.8, alpha=0.75 )+
  #geom_text(aes(label=data2$Attributes), vjust=1.5,colour="black")
  ggtitle("Something")+  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = "yyy", x = "xxx") + guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16))+ theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text( size = 14)) + theme(legend.title = element_text( size = 16))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white", linetype = "dotted"))
p
```

This results in a picture:

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: Wow, you're really going crazy asking a bunch of questions all about the same task. Does this really need to be three separate questions? Can you delete those that are no longer relevant to you? Focus on one problem at a time and let people answer that one first.

Comment: I think all are relevant and as I understand it is not recommended to ask 3 questions in one.

Comment: Q1. grid on top of imported image,Q 2 controlling plot size and position on top of image and Q3, set "alpha" on imported image if possible

Comment: `geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), alpha=0.15) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=seq(from=0, to=10, by=2.5), color="white")` after the `annotation_custom`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, just what I wanted, thanks.